# No abre Esquemas de URL admitido

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo este código donde llamo a la App BILLPOCKET y esto me funciona en ios pero en android no me abre la App.

```
  _launchURL() async {
    final resultadoTotal = widget.sumaAmount.toStringAsFixed(2);
    final url =
        'billpocket://identifier=2121&amount=$resultadoTotal&transaction=venta&usertoken=b9cac7478008f232d67974c03b510614c1ce7144328f8ffab122c18214a6fd6a&email=joks@hotmail.com&phone=7777885&reference=esta%20es%20una%20prueba';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
    print(url);
  }
}
```

en mi AndroidManifest.xml tengo el siguiente código como lo indica: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="billpocket" />
  </intent>

</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esos `schemes` son definidos para acciones del Sistema, como vez, están enlazados a acciones ya existentes.

```xml
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app makes calls -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app sends emails -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Lo que tu necesitas es deep links/app links, que lo puedes hacer usando este plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

```xml
    <!-- App Links -->
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
        <data
          android:scheme="https"
          android:host="[YOUR_HOST]" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Comment: y en flutter como lo llamaria? @diegoveloper

Comment: revisa el link que puse, de uni_links , ahí están las instrucciones de configuración y uso